# Python is stopping before running a loop

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with this code. It will run normally until it gets to the loop (def Game) and just stops there. I did have it as an if statement but that still didn't work. Please note that this may be a bit messy.

```
import random
import time 
GameInProgress = ("Yes")
TutorialDone = ("No")
ReplayGame = ("Yes")
#Test purposes
PlayerName = ("Lewis")
print ("Welcome to 'Guess The Word!")

def Game():
      GameInProgress = ("Yes")
      TutorialDone = ("No")
      ReplayGame = ("Yes")
      #Test purposes
      PlayerName = ("Lewis")
      print ("Welcome to 'Guess The Word!")
      WordSelected=("No")
      LettersGuessed=0
      print (TutorialDone)
      EnterName = input("Would you like to enter your name?").title()
```

Comment: `def Game():` is not a loop, it's a function, you just need to call it, with `Game()` at the end

Comment: Ok, seems to just be working now. Thank you.

Comment: btw, you don't need all those parentheses : `GameInProgress = ("Yes")`--> `GameInProgress = "Yes"`

Comment: Thanks. I'll change them and note that.

Comment: I had a Game() at the end it just wasn't running. It's working now. Thank everyone for their help.

Answer (score 3):

`def Game():` is not a loop, it is a function it does not execute until you call it.
you can call a python function in this way

`Game()`

if you want to call the same function again and again simply you can call the function inside a for or while loop:

```
   while(condition):
       Game()
```

if your are very beginner follow some tutorials 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm